# Is the syntax used in Arduino entirely C++ or is there some special syntax occassionally

Tags: c++, c, arduino, arduino-c++

```
// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(1000);                       // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(1000);                       // wait for a second
```

I am new to Arduino with very  basic C experience, though also starting to learn C++ because I hear Arduino is based on C++.
My key question for now is how does the code above implement a loop (runs the code  forever) without a "while' or 'for' keyword? or is there a special function named 'loop' that does the magic?

Comment: That this code runs forever, is because the "arduino executable environment" calls it in a specific way (similar to `main()`).

Comment: Notably, writing `void loop()` in C would be wrong, since that's an obsolete style function. In C++ it is fine since `()` is the same as `(void)` there. But in C you should always write `void loop (void)`.

Comment: @Lundin but it is C++ so there is no problem. `C` tag is wrong here

Comment: @Lundin, as this is a _definition_ `void loop() { ...}` _is_ valid C and _is_ the same as `void loop(void) { ... }` The `(void)` is only required in a declaration to indicate the function takes no arguments. In the declaration it is obvious there are no arguments, not even old-style K&R ones.

Comment: @koder As I said, it is obsolete style. Since 22 years back in fact. It is still valid for now (C17) but might become invalid at any moment. C17 6.11.6 "The use of function declarators with empty parentheses (not prototype-format parameter type declarators) is an obsolescent feature."  We shouldn't use obsolete C when writing new programs. Similarly, K&R style function definitions are also obsolete since forever.

Comment: All official Arduino source is open-source.  See for yourself.  But the short answer is yes, the main functions and most libraries are bloated and slow syntactical sugar over C++.  If you want to learn how to develop embedded systems on microcontrollers, learn C for general use and assembly language for the processors where you need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in the main function there is

```
int main(void)
{
   /*  .... */
   setup();
   /*.......*/
   for(;;) loop();
```

The main is hidden from you. There is no magic, `setup` and `loop` are normal functions called from 'main'. Everything is very simple.

Arduino is just C++ and g++

The `main` function in arduino is declared as `weak` and you can write your own `main` function replacing the original one like in this example:

[image]

The first sketch replaces the Arduino main with my one (which does nothing) and it is clearly visible in the code size.

Comment: There are a lot of semicolons in your `for` statement.

Comment: It's a bit more complex than that.  The .ino is preprocessed.  You can't declare templates in the .ino file, and last time I checked, you can't use lambdas either, While the entire set of c++17 featires are available in additional ..cpp modules.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy did I wrote anything about the lambdas and templates?

Comment: @0___________ No you haven't. My point is that these are occasional limitations on the syntax.  Occasional different syntaxes being part of the question, in the title.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy for the sake of Arduino use you can assume no difference. If someone wants to program a bit advanced way - that person will not use Aurduino Ide for sure.

Comment: @0___________ ???   "that person will not use Aurduino Ide for sure."..  I would make the total opposite assumption for someone who describes him/herself as "I am new to Arduino with very basic C experience", In fact, I would recommend to a beginner that they use the Arduino IDE.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy `"If someone wants to program a bit advanced way"`

Comment: @0___________  If someone wants to program in a bit advanced way, they have to add .ccp modulees to their arduino IDE project.  There are dozens of open source advanced projects done just like that, if only most 3d printer firmwares.

Comment: @0___________   OK. Does that mean that the main() function is actually called after the definition of the loop() and setup() functions?

Comment: @blessedk definition is compile time. execution is when your micro executes compiled and linked program. Both are not related.

Comment: @0___________ what I mean is that since the loop() function is actually invoked inside the main function, then it must be pre-defined before the main() function runs right? I understand that Arduino does not show the main function, but if it were to show it, I am guessing it would appear below the definition of the loop and setup functions right?

Comment: @blessedk No it does not have to. Only finvtion prototypes at needed. `void loop();` and `void setup();` Functiuons can be defined  in any other compilation unit - in this case in your .ino file.

Comment: @0___________ Yes you are absolutely right. Just tried out a small code on codeblocks with the definition below the main() and it worked. Thanks a lot.